# ¿Como puedo obtener el tipo de dato de un atributo nil "nulo" en swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
 func Deserialize(_ json:Dictionary<String, Any>)  {
        for (keyName, value) in json {
            if let type = self.value(forKey: keyName) as? String{
                print("El valor con la etiqueta es de tipo estring")
            }
            if self.responds(to: NSSelectorFromString(keyName)) && !keyName.contains("fecha") {
                if let newValue = value as?  NSString{
                  self.setValue(newValue, forKey: keyName)
                } else if let newValue = value as? Bool{
                    self.setValue(newValue, forKey: keyName)
                } else if let newValue = value as? Int{
                    self.setValue(newValue, forKey: keyName)
                } else if let newValue = value as? Double{
                    self.setValue(newValue, forKey: keyName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Fran. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. La pregunta ha de ser mejor explicada. Mira [ask] para mejorarla.  Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Buenos días.

Primero te aconsejo usar tipos básicos de Swift e intentar usar lo menos posible objetos de objective-C como `Dictionary<String, Any>` para esto usa `[String:Any]`

Respondiendo a tu duda, ya sabes cual es tu tipo de objeto `Any` ya que `Any` también es un tipo, solo que genérico.
Otra cosa es que `Any` se pueda o no castear a otro tipo como `String`, `Bool` etc mediante `objAny as? String`

Un saludo!